# Determine 1-based line and column number given absolute 0-based index of string (C#)

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, given a string and a 0-based index value, how can I determine the 1-based line and column numbers?

This should work for strings that come from various platforms with different line ending conventions.

**Edit:** I [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51025182/114) that works in a variety of scenarios and is concise. I'm open to other answers that can prove they are either faster and/or correct using examples with varying line endings and number of lines.

Comment: `how can I determine the 1-based line and column number` please add more information as its unclear what you are asking

Comment: Do you need the 1-based values for display to humans?

Comment: 1-based means 1,2,3...etc as opposed to 0-based 0,1,2,3 - as you find with array indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that determines the overall # of line breaks in the source string, making the logic more concise:

```cs
public (int line, int column) GetLocation(string value, int position)
{
    var line = 1;
    var column = position + 1;

    var matches = new Regex("\r\n?|\n").Matches(value);
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
        var match = matches[i];
        if (match.Index >= position)
        {
            break;
        }

        line += 1;
        column = position + 1 - (match.Index + match.Length);
    }

    return (line, column);
}
```

Comment: Does this compile on your machine?

Comment: @LarsTech yes - I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (C# 7)

Comment: I guess this makes a Tuple under the hood.  Weird to see it.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of your question it seems like you want a feature similar to how text editors show a line and column number. Taking a stab at this idea, check out the function below. You can take a substring up until the target index, then split on the new line character `\n`. The number of lines is your line number because the substring only includes lines up to the target index. Intentionally ignoring carriage returns (`\r`) in the split ensures that they are counted in the index and have no effect on the result, thus ensuring cross platform compatibility. Finally, the length of the last column is the line number, again because the substring ends at the target index.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FindIndexPair("Hello\r\nWorld", 0)); // (1, 1)
        Console.WriteLine(FindIndexPair("Hello\r\nWorld", 4)); // (1, 5)
        Console.WriteLine(FindIndexPair("Hello\r\nWorld", 7)); // (2, 1)
        Console.WriteLine(FindIndexPair("Hello\r\nWorld", 11)); // (2, 5)

        Console.WriteLine(FindIndexPair("Hello\nWorld", 0)); // (1, 1)
        Console.WriteLine(FindIndexPair("Hello\nWorld", 4)); // (1, 5)
        Console.WriteLine(FindIndexPair("Hello\nWorld", 6)); // (2, 1)
        Console.WriteLine(FindIndexPair("Hello\nWorld", 10)); // (2, 5)
    }

    public static Tuple<int, int> FindIndexPair(string val, int index)
    {
        var upToIndex = val.Substring(0, index + 1);
        var lines = upToIndex.Split('\n');
        var lineNumber = lines.Count();
        var columnNumber = lines.Last().Length;
        return Tuple.Create(lineNumber, columnNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run it with FindIndexPair("Hello\r\nWorld", 5) it prints (1, 6) which is apparently a wrong value. Your whole approach is flawed because val.SubString counts the indetermined line ending characters. First you have to split into an array of strings, trimmed away \r and \n, thn you can return something meaningful.

Comment: Hi, @PepitoSh. That was actually intentional. I am assuming that the target index is counting line ending characters, and as such Substring fits. That being said, running `FindIndexPair("Hello\r\nWorld", 5)` according to my definition would be "give me the pairwise coordinates of the carriage return", which is at (1, 6). In this same example, line 2 character 1 would be at index 7. I think it depends on how the problem is interpreted.

Comment: Right. OP is ambiguous.

Comment: @Tyler you are correct, the 0-based index does include the line endings. That is a correct and reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Variant of the code of @tyler supporting `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`, like [`StringReader.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx):

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public static (int row, int col) RowColumn(string str, int ix)
{
    int row = 1, col = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < ix; i++)
    {
        char ch = str[i];

        if (ch == '\r')
        {
            // Skip the optional \n
            if (i + 1 < ix && str[i + 1] == '\n')
            {
                i++;
            }

            row++;
            col = 1;
        }
        else if (ch == '\n')
        {
            row++;
            col = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            col++;
        }
    }

    return (row, col);
}
```

Use it like:

```
Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\r\nWorld", 0)); // (1, 1)
Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\r\nWorld", 4)); // (1, 5)
Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\r\nWorld", 7)); // (2, 1)
Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\r\nWorld", 11)); // (2, 5)

Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\nWorld", 0)); // (1, 1)
Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\nWorld", 4)); // (1, 5)
Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\nWorld", 6)); // (2, 1)
Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\nWorld", 10)); // (2, 5)

Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\rWorld", 0)); // (1, 1)
Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\rWorld", 4)); // (1, 5)
Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\rWorld", 6)); // (2, 1)
Console.WriteLine(RowColumn("Hello\rWorld", 10)); // (2, 5)

var rc = RowColumn("Hello\rWorld", 10);
int row = rc.row;
int col = rc.col;
```